# Getting loading state of ember route

Tags: ember.js, ember-data, ember-router

I have the following query params in my route:

```
queryParams:
  search:
    refreshModel: true
```

When I change `search` param everything changes as expected and model reloads.

The problem is: How can I check if route is still refreshing?

PS: `model.isLoaded` is `true` since page loads first time.

UPD: What I am trying to achieve: I have ObjectsController and there is a search and a table inside of it. When user submits his query, I want to hide table and show a spinner.

Comment: Have a look at it http://emberjs.com/guides/routing/loading-and-error-substates/. It might helps

Comment: @Susai, already did it. What I am trying to achieve: I have ObjectsController and there is a search and table inside of it's view. When user submits his query, I want to hide table and show a spinner.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Solution that helped me.

Ember.Route has two useful events [loading](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Route.html#event_loading) and [didTransition](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Route.html#event_didTransition):

```
actions:
   loading: ->
     @controller.set('loading', true) if @controller
   didTransition: ->
     @controller.set('loading', false) if @controller
```

Then in tempalate:

```
..search form..
{{#if loading}}
   show spinner
{{else}}
   ..render collection..
{{/if}}
```

Answer (score 0):

As long as when the query parameters moves back into the model function of your route, the route should go back into the loading state please see my example bin

http://jsbin.com/felice

Comment: if i set the template at a granular level it works http://jsbin.com/guduha objects/loading vs loading. not entirely sure the reason to be honest, would have to look deeper into the state code

Comment: Yeah, I know it, but it looks weird. I have updated my problem's description. I don't want to hide search form and results at the same time, I want to get something like: {{here the search form goes}}{{#if loading}}spinner{{else}}results{{/if}}

Answer (score 0):

Your router is :

```
App.Router.map(function(){
  this.resource('objects', function(){      
    this.route('new');                      
  });  
});
```

If your ObjectsIndexRoute returns a promise that doesn't immediately resolve, Ember will try to find a loading route in the hierarchy

```
-objects.loading
-loading
```

'objects/loading' template will be rendered on the area where child templates(for example, objects/index) of the 'objects' template render.

Have a look at http://emberjs.com/guides/routing/loading-and-error-substates/ for more detail.

Working bin : http://jsbin.com/bomupe/1

I put search form in objects template and results in objects/index template. objects/loading template replaces objects/index when loading.

UPDATE:

JSBin: http://jsbin.com/wenuy/1 . To alternate 'loading' spinner and search results by using a boolean property.

Comment: What if I also have ObjectsNew route and I don't want to show search on this page. I know I can use outlets, but what of I also have Sorting in table header. so my Objects view will be: <table><thead>{{sorting}}</thead> <tbody>{{outlet}}</tbody><table>, my ObjectsIndex will be {{#each}}<tr>..</tr>{{/each}} and my ObjectsNew is <form>. Then my form will be in the table...
How can I show loading "spinner" only in the table body and do not wrap ObjectsNew with unnecessary table/search/sorting at the same time?

Comment: In your case, instead of opting application given loading, go for your own implementation. Have a property (say isloaded) and set it false before sending request to server and set it true after the request is resolved. Based on its value show the spinner and content alternatively (if-else block). If you are not satisfied, please give the jsbin with full requirement (i.e, include ObjectsNew). I will try further

Comment: "set it false before sending request to server and set it true after the request is resolved." - My main question is how can I do it ;)

Comment: @organium : I just updated my answer. I given jsbin where i demonstrated the idea how to do your requirement with controller property.

Comment: ```transitionTo``` doesn't return proper promise. My first solution was: @set('loading', true); @transitionTo(..some params...). then -> @set('loading', false). But it doesn't work.